# EditText ellipsize long text and then make the view editable on click/touch

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, ellipsize

I have `EditText` which I need to ellipsize and make sure the first characters are visible if the text is too long. But on click/touch event it should be editable and the cursor should be at the end of the line.

After searching the internet it seems that `android:ellipsize="end"` is not compatible with editable mode of the `EditText`. Indeed, if I set `edittext.setKeyListener(null)` ellipsize works, but then the view is not editable and i cannot set any `onClickListener` on it.

If i use `setFocusable(false)` instead of disabling `KeyListener` I do not get ellipsize effect.

My current code:

```
    v.setSelection(0);
    v.setFocusable(false);
    //v.setKeyListener(null);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setFocusable(true);
            v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            v.setEnabled(true);
            v.setSelection(v.getText().length());
        }
    });
```

xml:

```
android:lines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make work around with some other views? Like show `TextView` for `ellipsize` and `onclick` of `TextView` show `EditText instead of TextView` and keep the cursor position to the end of `EditText`